# java string equal

Tags: java, string

A string can be initialised in two ways :

```
String s="ABCD";
```

OR

```
String s=new String("ABCD");
```

Are these two same or different ??
Again I have noticed that

```
String s="ABCD";
String z="ABCD";
boolean b=s.equals(z);
```

results in true but

```
String s=new String("ABCD");
String z=new String("ABCD");
boolean b=s.equals(z);
```

results in false.
Can anyone please explain me why this happens??

Comment: I deny your premise: both snippets will place the value `true` in the variable. Perhaps you meant `s == z`?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
String s="ABCD";
String z="ABCD";
```

refer to the same Strings in memory pool.
Howewver

```
String s=new String("ABCD");
String z=new String("ABCD");
```

produce separate memory spaces for the Strings.
So the output is such.
This also answers your first question.

Comment: I don't think this is correct for the posted code.  `.equals()` checks equality, not identity.  Pooling has no effect here.

Comment: The idea of the memory pool is accurate. The fact that that has any effect on `equals` being wrong is not. `"ABCD".equals(new String("ABCD"))` will be `true`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it for == and not .equals().

Answer (score 10):

All your examples must result `true`, even [the second one](http://ideone.com/WVkWt)

Why? The `String` class has an overriden `equals` method that checks whether two strings are the same - on a char-by-char basis. 
Operator == on the other hand checks whether two string references point the same object.

So, for instance:

```
String a = new String("asd"); //new object, will add to pool though
String b = new String("asd"); //new object
String c = "asd"; //will use the pool
boolean b1 = (a == b); //false, different objects (same contents though)
boolean b2 = (a.equals(b)); //true, same contents
boolean b3 = (a == c); //false, different objects
boolean b3 = (a.equals(c)); //true, same contents
```

Few more things to notice is that Java pools strings. If you use a string literal somewhere in your code, the JVM will pool that value and when you use it again, somewhere else in your code, the JVM will detect it and point your reference to it. Strings are immutable, so this is perfectly safe.

Last thing I want to emphasize is the construct `String b = new String("asd");`. In this case, a new String object will be created (because of operator `new`). Even if "asd" already exists in the string pool, string `b` will point to a separate memory location, with a new object.

If "asd" didnt exist in the pool, then not only would `b` point to a non-pooled area, but also "asd" would be added to the pool, just in case (for future references).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you have to read and analyze the source code of String.class, especially the equals and intern method, and additionally you have to do a research on the memory structure of java.

## String#equals

```
/**
 * Compares this string to the specified object.  The result is {@code
 * true} if and only if the argument is not {@code null} and is a {@code
 * String} object that represents the same sequence of characters as this
 * object.
 *
 * @param  anObject
 *         The object to compare this {@code String} against
 *
 * @return  {@code true} if the given object represents a {@code String}
 *          equivalent to this string, {@code false} otherwise
 *
 * @see  #compareTo(String)
 * @see  #equalsIgnoreCase(String)
 */
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
if (this == anObject) {
    return true;
}
if (anObject instanceof String) {
    String anotherString = (String)anObject;
    int n = count;
    if (n == anotherString.count) {
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;
    int i = offset;
    int j = anotherString.offset;
    while (n-- != 0) {
        if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

## String#intern

```
/**
 * Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
 * <p>
 * A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the
 * class <code>String</code>.
 * <p>
 * When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
 * string equal to this <code>String</code> object as determined by
 * the {@link #equals(Object)} method, then the string from the pool is
 * returned. Otherwise, this <code>String</code> object is added to the
 * pool and a reference to this <code>String</code> object is returned.
 * <p>
 * It follows that for any two strings <code>s</code> and <code>t</code>,
 * <code>s.intern()&nbsp;==&nbsp;t.intern()</code> is <code>true</code>
 * if and only if <code>s.equals(t)</code> is <code>true</code>.
 * <p>
 * All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are
 * interned. String literals are defined in &sect;3.10.5 of the
 * <a href="http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/html/">Java Language
 * Specification</a>
 *
 * @return  a string that has the same contents as this string, but is
 *          guaranteed to be from a pool of unique strings.
 */
public native String intern();
```

## Memory Structure

http://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp

Answer (score -1):

When we calling the below statements

```
String s="ABCD";
String z="ABCD";
```

Then it will be checked in string pool and if already exists in pool then address is referenced to the variable.
But when we call `new` keyword then explicitly saying to create new memory.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure about this but i guss in secound example

```
String s=new String("ABCD");
String z=new String("ABCD");
```

It is declare like an object so when you try to check equality sure will give u `false`( object can't equal object)

Comment: They are indeed instantiating a `new String`, which allocates new memory that does not go into the global `String` pool when a `String` is declared that way. All Java `Object`s have the `equals` method, which by default does indeed only do a reference check (`this == obj`). However, `String`, and many other objects, `Override` that behavior to do a more in-depth check. The poster is mistaken; those objects will say that they are equal.