# Android Questions App Answer==MyAnswer not null

Tags: android

I make android questions app. I can not find the right answer. Answer list.

Right answer: String answer = quizList.get(position).getAnswer();

Button Click:

```
    buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            if (answer =="A"){

                lblsignboard.setText("Ok");

            }
            else
            {

                lblsignboard.setText("No");


            }
        }
    });
```

Answer = "A", but this code does not work. Always gives the answer is no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: use `equals()` to compare `Strings`. `answer.equals("A");`

Comment: answer.equals("A") checks value equality. == checks object/reference equality  http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/4252352

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java string equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541172/java-string-equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this way too, to keep you code working even the answer key is of different case. Use either `equals("A")` or `equalsIgnoreCase("a")`.

```
 buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer.equals("A") || equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
                lblsignboard.setText("Ok");
            }else{
                lblsignboard.setText("No");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are comparing strings in java,always use .equals

Because the function (.equals) checks the actual contents of the string, the == operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.

and now furthur using equalsignorecase you need not to worry about search string is in caps or small.

```
buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
                lblsignboard.setText("Ok");
            }else{
                lblsignboard.setText("No");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android we make use of two things to compare strings:
1. equals : this is used when you want to compare even case of the string.
2. equalsIgnoreCase: This is just for content comparison.
Here is the small illustration as how it works:

```
   String myString = "heLLo";

    if(myString.equals("hello"))
    {
     System.out.print("equals");
    }
    else if(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("hello"))
    {
        System.out.print("equalsIgnoreCase"); 
    }
```

Here equalsIgnoreCase will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Strings can only compare by .equals method not by ==. Also you have to check string is null or not because .equals method may invoke 
nullpointerexception and you app may crash.

```
    buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if(answer!=null &&(answer.equals("A")||equalsIgnoreCase("a"))) {
            lblsignboard.setText("Ok");
      } else {
            lblsignboard.setText("No");
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

String can compare is .equals or .eqalignorecase not a '==' sign.'==' using a int value compare.

```
String answer=item.get(position).getAnswer();
    if(answer!=null && (answer.equals("A")||equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
            Log.e("Comapare","----------Success"); 
    }else{
        Log.e("Comapare","----------not compare");
    }
```